# IndexError: , How can I check if the last element in the list is null in this scenario without defining a method?

Tags: python, tree, stack, traversal, indexoutofrangeexception

This is a leet code problem so there isn't a tree defined. But here's the TreeNode class definition: (not applicable for my question but here it is anyway):

```
Definition for a binary tree node.
class TreeNode:
def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
    self.val = val
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
```

So, this is the what I did which failed because the list could not be accessed when it was empty. The problem arises on the line indicated with ###.

```
class Solution:
def postorderTraversal(self, root: TreeNode) -> List[int]:
    stack=[]
    output=[]
    node = root
    while True:
        if node:
            if (node.right != None):
                stack.append(node.right)
            stack.append(node)
            node=node.left
        elif stack:
            check=stack.pop()
            if (check.right != None) & (check.right == stack[-1]):     ###
                node=stack.pop()
                stack.append(check)
            else:
                output.append(check.val)
                node=None
        else:
            break
    return output
```

Error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
if (check.right != None) & (check.right == stack[-1]):
Line 27 in postorderTraversal (Solution.py)
ret = Solution().postorderTraversal(param_1)
Line 57 in _driver (Solution.py)
_driver()
Line 68 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Thus, I added a method to perform the check for stack[-1] to avoid the out of range error, on the line indicated with #.

```
def check_stack(stack):
if stack:
    return stack[-1]
else:
    return None

class Solution:
def postorderTraversal(self, root: TreeNode) -> List[int]:
    stack=[]
    output=[]
    node = root
    while True:
        if node:
            if (node.right != None):
                stack.append(node.right)
            stack.append(node)
            node=node.left
        elif stack:
            check=stack.pop()
            if (check.right != None) & (check.right == check_stack(stack)): #
                node=stack.pop()
                stack.append(check)
            else:
                output.append(check.val)
                node=None
        else:
            break
    return output
```

Is there a simpler way(without creating a new method & less lines of code) to perform a stack[-1] check without affecting the order of the other conditional statements in this case ?

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  Your posted code is not legally indented, and it does *not* elicit the errors you imply, as there is no driving program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the `check_stack` function by using slicing to get the last element of the stack instead of accessing specific index.

In this case, if there is no elements in the stack, you will get empty list instead of `None`.

For example:

```
stack = [1,2]
stack[-1:] # 2

stack = []
stack[-1:] # []
```

Comment: Yes, I believe what you've suggested is what I did for at first (shown in my post). However, the stack is being popped right after the 'elif stack:' statement, so the stack in certain cases will be empty. 

I don't think there's a simple solution to re-position the pop statement while maintaining the overall flow and logic.

Comment: @MichaelWell You are right, I missed the `pop` under the `elif`. I've updated my solution.

Comment: Cool! That works, I know of slicing, but didn't think of using it. Thanks Gabip!